# Magento 2.1.7 customer login issue

Tags: magento2, login, data-migration

when I try to log in as a customer to shop I got notice error:

> "An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance."

When I register as a new customer to shop it seems to work ok - when I am automatically logged in after registration. When I try to re-login I get an error as above. Anyone also met such issue before?

link to shop: http://new.beautywebshop.be
My Magento version is Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

While we see the error in developer tools. it shows loginPost action  as 302 Not found error. Could you please check XML and Js files in server.

Could you please check the exception log, debug log and also in PHP error logs in server. you will find  information from it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually my log files doesnt generate any error / notice about this issue. I think all my files are on place, also just changed permissions to 755 - which file i should look for if exists?

Comment: Also noticed that product added to cart before is removed from it after login fail.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

Answer:

There are two missing columns in customer_entity table:

1. 'failures_num' and
2. 'first_failure'

Prolly because of customer migration from Magento 1.9.7 -> Magento 2.1. Adding it to the table fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's working 
After migration from 1.9.3 to Magento 2.1 I face the same issue and I try to solve this using below steps

Add two new fields in the **customer_entity** table

1. failures_num
2. first_failure