# Magento 2.2.3 an unspecified error occurred please contact us for assistance at customer login

Tags: login, magento2.2.3

I am unable to login to customer account it is giving error 'an unspecified error occurred please contact us for assistance'. I have checked my customer_entity table has columns 'failures_num' and 'first_failure'. Still the issue is there.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs, are you using any third party extension?

Comment: Yes I am using, and in error log it is not writing any error.

Comment: Have you tried to disable any of the the third party modules? Are there any which alter / customize the customer log in ?

Comment: check this if it helps https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179065/magento-2-1-7-customer-login-issue/179088

Comment: yes both the columns are available

Comment: have you resolved this issue ?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 17):

You can check error. Go to file
**vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php**
and put these lines

```
$message = $e->getMessage();
$this->messageManager->addError($message);
```

just before lines-

```
$this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
```

now on front try to login and check error.

Comment: In my case I enabled `Sodium` extension and restarted server